# Elementary, unresolved import from my_app.views in Django (PyDev)

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

My project tree in home/DjangoProjects/django_bookmarks/env/django_bookmarks looks like:

```
django_bookmarks/ #project
    django_bookmarks/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    bookmarks/ #made with python manage.py startapp bookmarks
        __init__.py
        models.py
        test.py
        views.py
    manage.py
```

In ../bookmarks/views have:

```
from django.http import HTTPResponse

def main_page(request):
    output = '''
    <html>
    <head><title>%s</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ''' % (
    'Django Bookmarks',
    'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
    'Where you can store and share bookmarks!'
    )
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

In .../django_bookmarks/urls have:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from bookmarks.views import main_page # Unresolved import: main_page
# from bookmarks.views import * # Undefined variable: main_page in line below

...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^$', main_page)
)
```

EDIT:

In ../django_bookmarks/settings:

```
    # Django settings for django_bookmarks project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/home/novak/DjangoProjects/django_bookmarks/env/django_bookmarks/django_bookmarks/sqlite.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '0i_*)b7)hc0oy^7qyit47w%k65pwfo7e@p)k=7lho3)q5!mx+!'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_bookmarks.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_bookmarks.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

In ../django_bookmarks/wsgi:

```
"""
WSGI config for django_bookmarks project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.

"""
import os

# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "django_bookmarks.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_bookmarks.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

Django version is 1.5.1.
When I run the project (ctrl+F11) there is no error in console, just in-line error markers in Eclipse text editor. Eclipse apparently somehow runs previous version of code that works and in browser shows this previous version ignoring this error.
Earlier this same code was works well (this is code from the book) and therefore I think problem are some settings in Eclipse or eventually something in the way I created this project.
I was created project on this way http://blog.bixly.com/post/25093181934/setting-up-eclipse-for-python-django-development

I read here that people had problems with importing modules and mostly it was because the lack of **init**.py in app directory or some issue with PYTHONPATH settings. What I read did not help me to solve my problem.

*I'm a begginer in Django and this is the first time I write Django. This is an example from the book "Learning Website Development with Django", Ayman Hourieh.

Comment: is `bookmark` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: I don't think having bookmark in installed apps would make a difference when resolving the imports. But it will in fact continue to error out if he does correct his imports and it is not in installed apps

Comment: this is the key from your response "if you make Django project in virtual enviroment you use python interpreter from virtual enviroment. Thank you Paul Renton for your time."
It solves the problem... thumbs up....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,looks like I solved this problem.
Issue was in the way I made this Django project in Eclipse.
I was used python `virtualenv` which makes a little enviroment with its own `env/bin/python2.7` interpreter and this interpreter supposed to be selected in creating project dialog.
This Python have no Django preinstalled (of course), you have to install it if you want it.
I created this project in my `env/` made with `virtualenv` but leave interpreter settings on "Default" so PyDev was using python interpreter from system not `env/bin/python2.7` and could not found `env/django_bookmarks/bookmarks` app on his PYTHONPATH which caused `ImportError`.
Conclusion is actually logical, if you make Django project in virtual enviroment you use python interpreter from virtual enviroment.
Thank you Paul Renton for your time.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Make sure to use some relative imports :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to inform the Python interpreter to look one directory above.

Try a relative path import

```
from ..bookmarks.views import main_page
```

The '..' says to look a directory above to find the bookmarks package.

May I suggest to you a more robust pattern to accomplish this?

```
django_bookmarks/ #project
django_bookmarks/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
bookmarks/ #made with python manage.py startapp bookmarks
    __init__.py
    models.py
    test.py
    views.py
    urls.py # ADD another urls.py to your bookmarks app
manage.py
```

**In django_bookmarks/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
# from bookmarks.views import main_page # Remove this



# This directs Django to the urls.py within the bookmarks app
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', include('bookmarks.urls'))
)
```

**In bookmarks/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from bookmarks import views



# This directs Django to the urls.py within the bookmarks app
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', views.main_page)
    # Now you can add more bookmark urls to match to bookmark views
)
```

This pattern is more maintainable and allows all the bookmark url patterns to live inside bookmarks/urls.py.

Comment: Relative path import does't work in this case. I've tried what you've suggested above and get an ImportError: No module named bookmarks.
I think the problem is that bookmarks module is not on PYTHONPATH (I don't know why) and interpreter doesn't see this module but I don't know how to fix it yet.
Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you tried? Also maybe a snippet of your settings? This worked for me. Also I made a change to the include function. Try that instead

Comment: I tried this with both version of include function and don't work here. I'm just edited the question with ../django_bookmarks/settings, ../django_bookmarks/wsgi and some info below.

Comment: Sorry I can't determine what else might be wrong. Maybe if you post a bit more information I can figure it out. The code I posted worked for me in a project I created to simulate yours